# SQL statement in vb

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table named "Admin(a)"
And i have a SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Admin(a);
```

But (a) gives me a error.
How should i express Admin(a) in a sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the database. For MS SQL and MS Access you use square brackets around the identifier:

```
select * from [Admin(a)]
```

For MySQL you use backticks around the identifier:

```
select * from `Admin(a)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the name into square brackets for Sql Server, or if you following to ANSI standards - into double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM [Admin(a)];
SELECT * FROM "Admin(a)";
```